# Push notification is not received in Testflight

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Im trying to implement Apple Push notification.

It is working fine in Local environment. But it is not working in test flight.

1. I have got Automatic signing enabled.
2. I have included the APNS entitlement file in my build with Key `APS Environment` and Value `Development`.
3. I have used both of the following urls in my server,

   Sandbox: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195.

   Production: gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195.

But still the push notification is not received from testflight mode. Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your push notification is working fine on development but not on test flight.

You should check these as below:

1. Use the production SSL certificate to generate the .pem file on your push server when your app is using test flight.

[image]

2. Make sure your pem file and device token is right on your push server

[image]